# install Win7 SP1 with bcdedit failing

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, bcdedit

I'm getting the error 0x800F0A12 which is described [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/de-DE/windows7/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-service-pack-1-sp1-installation-error-0x800F0A12).

`bcdedit` says:

```
C:\>bcdedit.exe
Der Speicher für die Startkonfigurationsdaten konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

(English: Couldn't open the start configuration. Couldn't find the file.)

(off topic: how can I get those messages in English?)

I played around and I assume that is because the system partition C:\ is not on the first BIOS disk.

There are 4 disks in my PC. On one of them (shown as the 4th in Windows drive manager) contains Windows, whereby the system-reserved NTFS partition is the first primary and the second primary is my main Windows system partition. A few more partitions follow with other (non-NTFS) stuff. I was able to set the first two disks offline (via the Windows drive manager). For the 3rd disk, it says that it cannot set the BIOS 0 disk offline.

How can I ignore that and still install SP1?

I don't want to rewire/resetup my disks.

Answer (score -1):

You might encounter an issue during the installation of SP1 for Win7/R2 where the installer exits with: 0x800f0a12

This is due to the automount policy for your machine being set to disable.  We block the service pack installation in these cases because we need to be able to write information to the BCD store during install and with automount turned off, we are not able to.  To resolve this, re-enable automount and then install the service pack.  Quick steps to do this in case you forgot are:

1. Run DISKPART
2. automount enable
3. Restart
4. Install SP1

[link to full article on blogs.technet.com](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2011/02/17/windows-7-2008-r2-service-pack-1-fails-with-0x800f0a12.aspx)

Comment: The automount policy is already enabled. Also, the problem described there doesn't really match the problem I described. (bcdedit doesn't even find the BCD store although it is just there.)

Comment: Physically, it is some SATA disk in my computer. In Windows drive manager, it is shown as the 4th disk.

Comment: bcdedit expects BCD on fist disk - active partition, if it is not there it cannot find it. Are you are dual-booting via Linux and swapping disks?

Comment: Yes, that is what I expected. Yes, I'm dual-booting. I'm not swapping any disks. How can I install the SP1? I don't want to rewire the disks physically.

Comment: You can disconnect all disks, then connect only disk with Windows.

Comment: Posting AGAIN as time limit for edits reached!...You can disconnect all disks, then connect only disk with Windows. To be sure that this disk will boot write again a Windows 7 MBR to disk and a Windows 7 PBR to active partition (you should have a Windows 7 recovery CD or USB ready !)  BCD should be on active partition in \Boot folder. After booting to this only disk install SP1. Then reconnect all disks as they were before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2941/discussion-between-snayob-and-albert)

Comment: What do you mean by disconnect? I don't want to physically change anything. Also I don't want to change the MBR. Also, my computer doesn't have any CD drive so that is not an option. If you know any solution, I think it should go here and not in chat.